# Is it possible to rename columns?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, database-schema, google-cloud-spanner

Is it possible to issue something like

```
RENAME COLUMN col1 col2
```

in Google Cloud Spanner?  It looks from the DDL that this isn't possible; if not, is this a design choice or a limitation whilst in Beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Currently you can only do the following with regard to altering columns in a table:

- Add a new one
- Delete an existing one, unless it's a key column
- Change delete behavior (cascading or not)
- Convert between `STRING` and `BYTES`
- Change length of `STRING` and `BYTES`
- Add or remove `NOT NULL` modifier

A work around is possible by following these steps in order:

- Add the new column to your table
- Update your code to read to from both columns
- Update your code to only write to the new one
- Run a Cloud Dataflow job to migrate the data from the old column to the new column
- Update your code to only read from the new column
- Drop the old column

Keep in mind the above steps will not work for the primary key column, you'll have to do by creating a new table, and doing the data migration that way.

Comment: Dan - thanks for the hints.  How would propose going about running a Cloud Dataflow job that performs the migration? Is there anything built in to allow it to get/stream data from Cloud Spanner?

Comment: Unless you already have a large dataset, just writing any old process to query read and write everything in a single thread would be sufficient to get the job done.