# Renaming columns and tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Does the spanner supports renaming of columns and tables? That would be helpful while managing schema changes along with creating a new table from an existing one in a single statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot rename a column or a table. Other kinds of alterations are possible, but not renaming. A work-around for renaming columns is available in this answer: [Is it possible to rename columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506782/is-it-possible-to-rename-columns)

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer from Mike Curtiss is out of date.

I just tried the following in Google Cloud console and it worked:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo RENAME TO Bar
```